# How do you run a PHP script every 1 minute using a plist file with launchd (launchctl) in MacOS?

Tags: php, cron, plist, launchd, launchctl

So how do you run a PHP script once every 1 minute using a plist file with launchd (launchctl) in MacOS? This was a question I had that took forever to find the answer to, but I did eventually! I'm using my answer to make jobs on a Mac instead of `cron` or `crontab`, which is what you would normally use in Linux/Unix. Checkout my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

Create a new plist file `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.yourusername.yourscripttype.plist` and add the follow code to it, changing everything that should be changed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.yourusername.yourscripttype</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/absolute/path/to/php</string>
      <string>/absolute/path/to/app/subfolders/script.php</string>
    </array>
    <!-- <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/MoodleError.out</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/MoodleError.err</string> -->
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/absolute/path/to/app/</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
      <integer>60</integer>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Set permissions for this plist file:

`chmod 644 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.yourusername.yourscripttype.plist`

Confirm permission for your new file matches the existing plist files:

`ls -l ~/Library/LaunchAgents/`

Load the new file:

`launchctl load com.yourusername.yourscripttype.plist`

You should be good to go.

### Notes

- `com.whatevername.whateverscript.plist` is convention in MacOS, so use it.
- Manually test your PHP script with `launchctl start ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.yourusername.yourscripttype.plist`
- **WARNING:** Uncomment the `StandardOutPath` and/or `StandardErrorPath` lines in the above file if you want to see script output or errors to confirm your script is running properly, but **DON'T LEAVE THEM IN OR ELSE YOU'LL BE ADDING TO THE LOG FILES EVERY MINUTE WHICH WILL QUICKLY DESTROY YOUR SYSTEM'S MEMORY!**

```
    <!-- <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/MoodleError.out</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/MoodleError.err</string> -->
```